# jQuery, Add an increasing number to the end of a varaibles each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I am making a new object via my prototype. On click of an element I want to create a new object of the same name, but add a number that increase every time to the end of the name. here is my code:

```
<p class="clickMe">click me</p>

<script>
function person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
this.firstName = first;
this.lastName = last;
this.age = age;
this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
}

(".clickMe").click(function(event) {
 var i;
  if (i == 'undefined') { 
    i = 1;
  } else {
    i = i++;
  }
  var myFather[i] = new person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue"); 
  // so on click 2 the name would be : myFather2, then on click 3 myFather3 and so on..
 }
 </script>
```

What is proper syntax for this part:

```
 myFather[i]
```

here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k75fbvfs/5/

Comment: You probably want to use an array instead of numbered variables. Which you are already kindof using with `[i]`.

Comment: Use an array, https://jsfiddle.net/t9u1oxrn/ or an object https://jsfiddle.net/rqeytbvc/

Comment: Nick, did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array, and define it, as well as the iterator `i` outside fo the click handler:

```js
function person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  this.age = age;
  this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
}

var fathers = [],
    i = 0; // Start counting at 0

$(".clickMe").click(function(event) { // $ was missing
  fathers.push(new person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue"));
  console.log(fathers[i], i, fathers.length); // Also log `i`
  i++; // You don't need to assign `i`, `++` modifies the variable.
});
//^ missing `);`
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="clickMe">click me</p>
```

Here's an [**updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/k75fbvfs/6/).